# Como manipular células de um vetor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, random

Criei um programa que preenche um vetor de 10 posições com números aleatórios entre 0 e 20. Agora preciso mostrar um novo vetor manipulado, onde cada célula é a soma dela mesma e das células anteriores.

Dessa forma passo o vetor original:

```
[2, 1, 20, 5, 17, 19, 14, 4, 18]
```

e pretendo receber como vetor manipulado:

```
[2, 3, 25, 35, 82, 166, 327, 644, 1302]
```

Minha tentativa foi a seguinte:

```
import random

vetor = random.sample(range(21), 10)

print(f"Vetor Original {vetor}")

vetor[0] = vetor[0]

vetor[1] = vetor[0] + vetor[1]

vetor[2] = vetor[0] + vetor[1] + vetor[2] 

vetor[3] = vetor[0] + vetor[1] + vetor[2] + vetor[3]

vetor_manipulado = vetor[0], vetor[1], vetor[2], vetor[3]

print(f"Vetor Manipulado {vetor_manipulado}")
```

Como manipular cada célula desse vetor?

Comment: E a parte que tenta fazer o novo vetor? Não chegou a fazer?

Comment: Atualizei a questão

Answer (score 4):

Basta fazer o que o enunciado pede: cada valor do novo será o valor somado com os anteriores.

```py
def accumulate(iterable):
  accumulated = []
  for value in iterable:
    accumulated.append(value + sum(accumulated))
  return accumulated


vetor = [2, 1, 20, 5, 17, 19, 14, 4, 18]
acumulado = accumulate(vetor)

print(acumulado)
# [2, 3, 25, 35, 82, 166, 327, 644, 1302]
```

Comment: Obrigada, eu estava fazendo um a um, por isso tava tão longo

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é guardar a soma até o momento, e usá-la para atualizar cada elemento:

```
vetor = [2, 1, 20, 5, 17, 19, 14, 4, 18]

soma_acumulado = 0
acumulado = []
for n in vetor:
    soma_parcial = n + soma_acumulado
    acumulado.append(soma_parcial)
    soma_acumulado += soma_parcial

print(acumulado) # [2, 3, 25, 35, 82, 166, 327, 644, 1302]
```

Dessa forma você não precisa chamar `sum` várias vezes, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/500134/112052) (que também funciona, claro, mas a desvantagem é que ela sempre soma todos os elementos já existentes desde o início, o que me parece desnecessário, pois guardando o total acumulado até então, você só precisa atualizar com os valores novos, em vez de percorrer todos os elementos desde o início toda hora).

---

Apenas para comparar, fiz um teste rápido com o módulo `timeit`:

```
def com_sum(iterable):
  accumulated = []
  for value in iterable:
    accumulated.append(value + sum(accumulated))
  return accumulated

def com_total_parcial(iterable):
    soma_acumulado = 0
    acumulado = []
    for n in iterable:
        soma_parcial = n + soma_acumulado
        acumulado.append(soma_parcial)
        soma_acumulado += soma_parcial
    return acumulado

from timeit import timeit

# executa 100 vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 100, 'globals': globals() }

# lista com mil números
vetor = list(range(1000))

print(timeit('com_sum(vetor)', **params))
print(timeit('com_total_parcial(vetor)', **params))
```

Os tempos podem variar, pois depende de hardware e vários outros fatores, mas enfim, criei uma lista com mil números e rodei cada teste cem vezes. Na minha máquina os resultados foram (tempos em segundos):

```
7.2661133
0.04990649999999963
```

Ou seja, usando `sum` demorou cerca de 7 segundos, enquanto que guardando a soma parcial demorou menos que 5 centésimos de segundo. Aqui podemos ver como faz diferença chamar `sum` várias vezes (pois ele precisa percorrer todos os elementos já computados e somar tudo de novo). Já com a soma parcial, isso não é necessário, bastando somar o novo valor a cada iteração.

Claro que para listas pequenas a diferença será insignificante, mas não se esqueça que [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/).

Comment: Compreendi, obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução

```py
def acc(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        yield i + s
        s *= 2
        s += i

vetor = [2, 1, 20, 5, 17, 19, 14, 4, 18]
*res, = acc(vetor)
print(res) # [2, 3, 25, 35, 82, 166, 327, 644, 1302]
```

ou sem o gerador

```py
def acc(a):
    s = 0
    ret = []
    for i in a:
        ret.append(i + s)
        s *= 2
        s += i
    return ret


vetor = [2, 1, 20, 5, 17, 19, 14, 4, 18]
res = acc(vetor)
print(res) # [2, 3, 25, 35, 82, 166, 327, 644, 1302]
```